# How to make each fragment make it's own implementation for parent activity button listener

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using navigation component.

I don't want each fragment to have the next button.
My goal is putting that next button in activity, and each fragment implements its own destination and maybe doing some validation.

What is the best way to achieve my goal?